# How can i copy one cell data in a column and then paste it untill another value comes in the column through VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

The code I used

```
Sub copypaste()
'
' copypaste Macro
'

'
    Range("B2:B8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FillDown
    Range("B9:B10").Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Range("B11:B13").Select
    Selection.FillDown
End Sub
```

I have this sheet:

[image]

And I want output through VBA code as my actual sheet is very big like this:

[image]

Comment: Where is the code you have tried and what problems are you having with it?

Comment: a while loop along each row will work, what did you try so far?

Comment: No VBA needed, there are some very user friendly build in functions to tackle this. Also, please include your own attempt and tell us where you got stuck. Look at [ask] a question with a [mcve]

Comment: @JvdV I completely understand that my question is vague but the reason I asked it because I don't know VBA and I am stuck with a real life problem. When I googled and looked for the answer, VBA seemed to be a common answer. Hence my question

Comment: @henrywongkk I am sorry but I did not try anything as I have no knowledge of VBA but I do know that this problem of mine can be solved by VBA

Comment: @braX hi I have zero knowledge of VBA but have an idea that this can be resolved by it, hence thought of asking VBA experts. Need help

Comment: @JvdV no I totally understand that but I tried to resolve it but just couldn't solve it. I don't work with excel much, I need this excel sheet for my python work. This was one problem I wanted to solve before using the sheet for python. Hence my low knowledge on excel. If there is any way apart from excel then please just let me know what it is, I will then google it and work on my own

Comment: If you tried it, then include your attempt. Anything is better than nothing.

Comment: @JvdV I have included the code and I know it's wrong on many levels but that was the reason I didn't include it, not that I want others to do my code. If you could advice anything even if its inbuilt function then that would be a great help too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid VBA in case you not sure how to use it in the first place. There are many cool build-in features to assist you in a case like yours:

- Select range `B1:B17`
- Goto tab `Start` > Select `Find & Select` > Choose `Go To Special` > Choose `Blanks`
- Now all empty cells in your range are selected with cursor in top one. Type `=B2` and hit key-combo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot that resolved my problem. Will next time post questions in a better way.

Comment: @JvdV I just tried this, but didn't work on my Excel. Could it be because of the spanish version?

Comment: The last one, just found it on the internet, need to hit Ctrl + Enter, Ctrl + D doesn't work for me. Instead typing the formula and Enter, if you press Ctrl + Enter will spare you the last step @JvdV.

Comment: That's nice information. I wasn't aware that this would depend on Locale. And pressing `CTRL`+`ENTER` is even better ;). I edited the answer (less steps is even better). Thanks